# Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket SerializationException when using RedisSessionStateProvider

Tags: c#, redis, owin, openid-connect, session-state-provider

I'm using the Owin OpenIdConnectAuthentication module in my app, and am trying to move my session state to Redis.  I'm using `Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider` for this.  When I update my web.config to add the `RedisSessionStateProvider` I start getting this error:

> Type 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket' in Assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.

**Stack Trace**

```
[SerializationException: Type 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket' in Assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.]
   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type) +10951483
   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context) +230
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo() +121
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder) +182
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder) +51
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck) +540
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck) +131
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph) +12
   Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisUtility.GetBytesFromObject(Object data) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f55792526e6d9089\src\Shared\RedisUtility.cs:65
   Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisUtility.AppendUpdatedOrNewItemsInList(ChangeTrackingSessionStateItemCollection sessionItems, List`1 list) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f55792526e6d9089\src\Shared\RedisUtility.cs:37
   Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisConnectionWrapper.TryUpdateIfLockIdMatchPrepare(Object lockId, ISessionStateItemCollection data, Int32 sessionTimeout, String[]& keyArgs, Object[]& valueArgs) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f55792526e6d9089\src\RedisSessionStateProvider\RedisConnectionWrapper.cs:323
   Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisConnectionWrapper.TryUpdateAndReleaseLockIfLockIdMatch(Object lockId, ISessionStateItemCollection data, Int32 sessionTimeout) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f55792526e6d9089\src\RedisSessionStateProvider\RedisConnectionWrapper.cs:350
   Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean newItem) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f55792526e6d9089\src\RedisSessionStateProvider\RedisSessionStateProvider.cs:408
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +565
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnEndRequest(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +139
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Am I missing some config somewhere?  All the documentation I can find about serializing `AuthenticationTicket` objects is for OAuth *server* implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were using the [AspNetAuthSessionStore sample](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#tests/Katana.Sandbox.WebServer/AspNetAuthSessionStore.cs) from Katana.  Apparently this sample only works for InProc session state.  We made the following changes to resolve this issue by manually serializing the `AuthenticationTicket`:

```
    public Task<string> StoreAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        string key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        CheckSessionAvailable(httpContext);
        //httpContext.Session[key + ".Ticket"] = ticket;       // Remove
        var ticketSerializer = new TicketSerializer();         // Add
        var ticketBytes = ticketSerializer.Serialize(ticket);  // Add
        httpContext.Session[key + ".Ticket"] = ticketBytes;    // Add

        return Task.FromResult(key);
    }
```

Comment: In my case `httpContext.Session` in `RetrieveAsync` is null right after authentication. I tried to add `app.UseAspNetAuthSession();` in `startup.cs` before `app.UseCookieAuthentication()`, but that didn't help. Any suggestions?